# Mouse not working in remote desktop connection

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, remote-desktop, mouse

I am connecting from a work computer running Windows 7 Enterprise to my home computer running Windows 8.1 Pro. I am able to connect and the keyboard works just fine, but the mouse is not visible or usable in the remote system. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to make sure: Are you using Windows' Remote Desktop to connect, or some other program (LogmeIn, Teamviewer, etc.)?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I am using Remote Desktop, the client that comes with Windows. Thank you!

Comment: Any "mouse helper" type utilities running on the Windows 8.1 machine?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Not really. That's why I'm wondering what could it be, for I know MS has released hotfixes for these kind of issues before.

Comment: Well I RDP from my Windows 7 machine to Windows 8.1 plenty, and my mouse always works. ;)  Perhaps disable all 3rd party start-ups and services on the Win8.1 host and see if you can then connect?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I' ll try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably any of the below suggestions would help you to resolve this case:

1. Ensure, you Remote Desktop Connection > Local Resources settings are configured properly (Windows+r > mstsc > Local Resources tab).
2. Unplug and plug it back
3. Do a system restart of both the machine
4. Isolate the issue by remote from another machine and check the functionality of the mouse
5. Uninstall and Install the vendor's recent driver of the mouse

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you @vembutech. I'll try those things and update the thread.

Comment: @Aerozeek, Have you tried the steps?. What is your results?

Comment: The problem solved by itself (!). I don't recall doing anything to fix the issue but the next time I tried it worked. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 0):

[Chrome Remote Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en) is a free Chrome plugin. It could help you troubleshoot the issue even if you don't want to use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Even though OP's issue [resolved itself](https://superuser.com/questions/853757/mouse-not-working-in-remote-desktop-connection#comment1144559_853781), I'll leave this behind for others, like me, that come along with the issue.</sub>
Being unable to see the mouse you may have to get creative with your keyboard (using <kbd>tab</kbd> et cetera to get around), I've had this issue connecting to Windows Server 2012 (basically server of Win8).

If your issue is the same all you have to do is [disable the pointer shadow](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-disable-mouse-pointer-shadow-windows) (skip to `Alternative, you could type Mouse`, should be easier)

Other than [that suggestion](https://github.com/dorianj/CoRD/issues/26), looking online, people seemed to have had luck by [disallowing themes to change mouse pointers](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/62d38e39-b95b-4429-a64d-a88f56a6c8fb/ms-remote-desktop-mouse-cursor-acting-funny).

Answer (score 0):

The first solution is to connect a mouse in the remote computer.Usually this solves it.

However if you cannot or do not want to, you can try this:
When you open a remote desktop window you can see the grey-green message saying that your desktop is being shared. Starting from the bottom of your screen try to aim with the mouse pointer to this message box. If you click inside the box, keep the button down and drag the box to another place in the screen, then the pointer will reappear.